# User defined table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined

I am trying to pass a datatable to my procedure.

I have created a SQL Server user-defined table type as below:

```
 CREATE TYPE dbo.DT_SimQuestionWebTemp AS TABLE 
 (
        [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [SimId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
        [mobile] [nvarchar](25) NOT NULL,
        [LevelId] [int] NULL,
        [QuestionId] [int] NULL,
        [Question] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
        [Answer1] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Answer2] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Answer3] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Answer4] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Answer5] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
        [Status] [int] NOT NULL
 )
```

I am trying to drop the table to create again with different schema
using the below syntax.

```
drop table DT_SimQuestionWebTemp
```

however I am getting an error:

> Cannot drop the table 'DT_SimQuestionWebTemp', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

and I have permission to drop tables and also I am able to use the table from the stored procedure. However I am not able to drop it or select from it through a normal query.

Any idea how to see the table and drop it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [`drop type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174407.aspx) not `drop table`

```
 DROP TYPE dbo.DT_SimQuestionWebTemp
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
DROP TYPE dbo.DT_SimQuestionWebTemp;
```